# Flask framework is using GET instead of specifying POST method

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to add data in dictionary through form using post method. But it's not working. form is working with get method but not post.
I read many similar posts but could'nt understand so posting here.
Please help me to locate the problem and solve it.

Python Code

```
@app.route('/add_card',methods=["GET","POST"])
def add_card():
    if request.method == "POST":
        card = {"question": request.form['question'],
                "answer": request.form['answer']}
        db.append(card)
        return redirect(url_for('card_view',index=len(db)-1))

    else:
        return render_template("add_card.html")
```

Form code:

```
 <form methods=" POST">
        <p>
            Question:
            <input type="text" name="=question">
        </p>
        <p>
            Answer:
            <input type="text" name="'answer">
        </p>
        <button type="submit">
            Create
        </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: The problem could be in how you are submitting the form. Show us the front-end code please

Comment: you have a typo in your form. it is `method=post` not method**s**. Remove the s (and the extra space) and the post should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
<form methods=" POST">
```

with:

```
<form method="POST">
```

You have an extra **s**, making the form use GET to submit.

As an aside, if you have many forms in your app, [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) may become handy.

Comment: Hi @Derlin Thank you for the response and the resource you shared is very helpful to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="{{ url_for('add_card') }}" method="post">
     <p>
        Question:
        <input type="text" name="question">
    </p>
    <p>
        Answer:
        <input type="text" name="answer">
    </p>
    <button type="submit">
        Create
    </button>
</form>
```

Use `<form method="POST">` Instead of `<form methods="POST">` .

Its better use `url-binding`  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#url-building

Comment: Hi @Mamun
Thank you for the response. I found that I had an extra s and space in the code which were creating problem.

Would you like to tell me if it's necessary to provide 'action' in flask or it's recommended?
Thank you

Comment: Its recommended. It is called  'url-building'  see more from [https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#url-building](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#url-building)